# App crashes when moves from login activity to next activity in onDataChange method

Tags: java, android, firebase

The app is to make a person login as admin if he has a registered phone and password
But when the code retrieves the data in realtime database in firbase 
I was following firebase tutorial on youtube .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z2awGCuDdM&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlqmH_VfWneUjfuqhreUz-O&index=9
 my loginActivity class is given below

```
package com.example.clone;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.clone.Model.Details;
import com.example.clone.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG ="Started" ;
    private EditText phoneInput;
    private EditText passwordInput;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private TextView AdminLink, NotAdminLink;


    private String parentDbName = "Users";
    private CheckBox chkBoxRememberMe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        phoneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        AdminLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.admin_panel_link);
        NotAdminLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.not_admin_panel_link);

        chkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chbk);
        Paper.init(this);

        AdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginBtn.setText("Login Admin");
                AdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                NotAdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                parentDbName = "Admin";
            }
        });

        NotAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginBtn.setText("login");
                AdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                NotAdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                parentDbName = "Users";

            }
        });


        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String phone = phoneInput.getText().toString();
                final String password = passwordInput.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                    phoneInput.setError("Empty");
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    passwordInput.setError("Empty");
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference();

                    if (chkBoxRememberMe.isChecked()) {
                        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.UserPhoneKey, phone);
                        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.UserPasswordKey, password);
                    }

                    myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).exists())
                            {
                                Details usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Details.class);


                                if (usersData.getPhone().equals(phone))
                                 {
                                    if (usersData.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                                        if(parentDbName.equals("Admin")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "admin welcome!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);

                                        }
                                        else if(parentDbName.equals("Users"))
                                        {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The input user does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

the Details class is

```
package com.example.clone.Model;

public class Details {
    private String name, password, phone;

    public Details() {
    }

    public Details(String name, String password, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() { return phone; }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

the error showing in logcat is.

```
   --------- beginning of crash
2020-04-10 14:54:57.443 22896-22896/com.example.clone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.clone, PID: 22896
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:413)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:199)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:178)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:580)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:550)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:420)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:212)
        at com.example.clone.LoginActivity$3$1.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:102)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:183)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

[the screenshot given below is the screenshot of the firebase console of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpDGL.png)

Comment: Probably name, password or phone, one of them is Long Type

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my question with a screenshot of the firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Details` class you have (3 x `String`) fields:

```
String name;
String password;
String phone
```

Base on the screenshot, I see that in Firebase your `phone` fields for some objects are "as number" (`Long` in Java) but for others "as text" (`Long` in Java).

You can try to temporarily remove `phone` field from your `Details` class.
If it will work after that - you know where is the problem (and probably you have to fix it manually in Firebase)

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of my Firebase structure

Comment: @shantanusrivastava you have to decide. Are you storing phone `as number` (Long) or `as String`. Currently I see that they are mixed in Firebase. First of all, you have to fix it there.

Comment: @shantanusrivastava updates my answer. Check if after temporarily remove `phone` field it will work.

Comment: actually using the phone field it is checking the validity on the user and it is also acting as a parent node.So I cannot remove the phone field

Comment: @shantanusrivastava did you try to fix types on Firebase?

Comment: Yes I tried fixing the problem that you pointed out but then also the error in the logcat was the same line    Details usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Details.class);

Comment: Try to remove all fields from `Details` class and add it one by one. There is no different way to find a problem.